# shared preferences not being saved

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In my activity i am updating the user interface according to the preferences stored. code for updateUI is as follows:

```
private void updateUI()
{
    //preferences = getSharedPreferences(Select.PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

    toggle = (Button)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
    incommingEdit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.IncommingEditButton);
    outgoingEdit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.outgoingEditButton);
    missedEdit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.missedEditButton);
    save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
    cancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
    incommingCheck = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.incommingCheck);
    outgoingCheck = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.outgoingCheck);
    missedCheck = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.missedCheck);
    incommingTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.incommingTextView);
    outgoingTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outgoingTextView);
    missedTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.missedTextView);

    //Disable all the edit buttons until their checkboxes are checked.
    incommingEdit.setEnabled(false);
    outgoingEdit.setEnabled(false);
    missedEdit.setEnabled(false);

    //Display the messages in the text views.
    incommingTextView.setText(preferences.getString("incommingMsgPhone", "Currently there are no messages saved."));
    outgoingTextView.setText(preferences.getString("outgoingMsgPhone", "Currently there are no messages saved."));
    missedTextView.setText(preferences.getString("missedMsgPhone", "Currently there are no messages saved."));

    //Check the check boxes.
    if(preferences.getInt("incommingPhone", 0) == Calls.INCOMING_TYPE)
    {
        incommingCheck.setChecked(true);
        incommingEdit.setEnabled(true);
    }

    if(preferences.getInt("outgoingPhone", 0) == Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE)
    {
        outgoingCheck.setChecked(true);
        outgoingEdit.setEnabled(true);
    }

    if(preferences.getInt("missedPhone", 0) == Calls.MISSED_TYPE)
    {
        missedCheck.setChecked(true);
        missedEdit.setEnabled(true);
    }

    //Check if the application is on or off and set the text of the button.
    //preferences = getSharedPreferences(Select.PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean on = preferences.getBoolean("isOn", false);
    if(!on)
        toggle.setText("Turn On");
    else
        toggle.setText("Turn off");
}
```

Here is how i am saving all these preferences:

```
save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Save all in the preference file and exit.
            //preferences = getSharedPreferences(Select.PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
            Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putInt("incommingPhone", incomming);
            editor.putInt("outgoingPhone", outgoing);
            editor.putInt("missedPhone", missed);

            editor.putString("incommingMsgPhone", incommingMsg);
            editor.putString("outgoingMsgPhone", outgoingMsg);
            editor.putString("missedMsgPhone", missedMsg);

            editor.commit();
            finish();
        }
    });
```

my UI is updated properly second time i run my application but around third or fourth time i get default preference values. i even tried using getdefaultpreferences instead of getsharedpreferences, but no luck.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem with getStringSet, the documatation helped there

> Note that you must not modify the set instance returned by this call.
>   The consistency of the stored data is not guaranteed if you do, nor is
>   your ability to modify the instance at all.

Answer (score 3):

Try clearing your editor before using it. In other words do:

```
Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.clear();
editor.putInt("incommingPhone", incomming);
editor.commit();
```

I have had exactly same problem like yours and this worked for me. For my whole code sample see [this post on my blog](http://looksok.wordpress.com/2012/09/21/sharedpreferences-not-saved-after-app-restart/)

Answer (score 2):

I am having a similar problem - my String variables are being retained, but nothing else is.
As a poor-man's workaround, I am saving everything as Strings.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
 preferences = activity.getSharedPreferences("Share", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`
```

Comment: thanks, but i tried this method as well, but somehow my preferences are getting deleted.

Answer (score -1):

it's example :

```
public void saveFavName(String what)
        {


             myPrefs= getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
             SharedPreferences.Editor es = myPrefs.edit();
             es.putString( "value", what); // add or overwrite someValue
                 es.commit(); // this saves to disk and notifies observers
        }
```